# Will CUDA10 + CUDNN + tensorflow work on Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, ubuntu-14.04

It is now Oct 29, 2018

After much googling, I have not found a definitive answer or any examples of people using the latest cuda10 for tensorflow on ubuntu 14.04.

My dilemma is whether to upgrade my OS (currently at 14.04) in order to run cuda9 so I can use the latest tensorflow version or use CUDA10 on my existing 14.04 install.

Note cuda9 does not support 14.04, however, Nvidia has indicated that 14.04 will be supported for cuda10.

So, any examples/experiences of people using tensorflow with cuda10 on ubuntu14.04 are keenly sought after!

Also note cuda10 is not specifically supported by tensorflow...yet...they say "soon". But TF can be built from source with cuda10.

This is a link for cuda10+tensorflow on ubuntu16.04: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22706

The short answer, I realize, is "try building it myself". Before I do that, I thought I'd ask around. Thanks.

Comment: ok. it'd be nice to have a reason for the downvote. I'm assuming I'm not the only person who will be confronted with this dilemma. I agree that it is a general sort of question...is there a better place for it? Or am I not clear in what I'm seeking?

Comment: Just a side note: you can try to build it inside a [Docker Container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container), which you can set to Ubuntu 14.04 so that you don't need to mess up with your system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether CUDA 10 can work well on Ubuntu 14.04, but I was managed to build TensorFlow with CUDA 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 with using [NVIDIA released docker image](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/tensorflow-release-notes/running.html#running).

- You can pull the 'TensorFlow Release 18.09' and try it on your current system.
- If the previous step does not work, consider upgrading your OS to 18.04.

I wrote down my installation experience on [this page](https://f-exp.gitbook.io/tensorflow-notebook/), you could read it for some detail if you need.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  Upgrading is in my future but too many of my projects tend to explode when I do that.  But being able to upgrade to cuda10 while still running 14.04 would be a good stepping stone.  Likely I will do a dual boot just to make sure all is recoverable.